# Using XSLT contains function does not work but xpath expression is good

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

Can somebody please tell me what is wrong with my xslt syntax ?

I already confirmed that my Xpath expression bellow is good and returning the right result :

```
/*[local-name()='animal']/*[local-name()='birth']/*[local-name()='date']
```

Now, I am trying to re-use this expression in XSLT with the "contains" function in order to obtain a true or false but it doesn't work.  I must me doing something wrong.

I tried this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output 
    method="html"
    encoding="UTF-8"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
    indent="yes" ></xsl:output>

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Test </title>
</head>
<body>

    <p> Birth date 1998-08-20 (true/false) : </p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/*[local-name()='animal']/*[local-name()='birth']"/>

</body>
</html>         
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='birth']">
    <xsl:value-of select="contains(/*[local-name()='date'], '1998-08-20')"> </xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks !!!  :-)))

Comment: How can you assert that your XPath is good when your code's not working, and how can you expect us to help you when you don't show the input XML document?  Please provide a [mcve] illustrating your problem.   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your XML, we can only guess. I would say that if this:

```
/*[local-name()='animal']/*[local-name()='birth']/*[local-name()='date']
```

works, then your root element's name must be `animal`. Therefore this:

```
/*[local-name()='birth']
```

cannot work, because the root element's name is not `birth` (a well-formed XML has one root element only).

--
P.S. You should never have to use a hack like `*[local-name()='xyz']`. Learn how to handle namespaces by using prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many slashes. In XPath when you start an expression with `/` it "jumps up" to the top of the tree, to the root node.

Your template match expression should just match the `birth` element (without a leading slash). Inside of that template, the context node is the `birth` element, so your `contains()` expression should not have a leading slash before the `date` element. An XPath statement without leading slashes will be selecting children relative from the context node.

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='birth']">
  <xsl:value-of select="contains(*[local-name()='date'], '1998-08-20')"/>
</xsl:template>
```